# invalid syntax when using pythonic style to code if, else statement

Tags: python

I am trying to use not more pythonic style to code my for-loop and if statement. Most of the time it works fine but this time with else-statement it returns me error message. Is there any grammar error in my code? How can I change it?

```
point_listSim = [(p.split('Reporting/'))[1] for p in point_list if 'Reporting/' in p else (p.split('reporting/'))[1]]
```

Comment: Just because you use a list comprehension does not make it more Pythonic

Comment: More pythonic would be easier to read.

Comment: [(p.split('Reporting/'))[1] if 'Reporting/' in p else (p.split('reporting/'))[1] for p in point_list] you are missplacing where if else should come.